# Wordpress how to get all user meta data by user ID?

Tags: wordpress

how to get all user meta data by user ID in Wordpress?

Answer (score 17):

@Boopathi Rejan nearly had it. Output all of the user meta by using the following code and then look through and find the values you

```
 $user_info = get_user_meta($current_user->ID);
 var_dump($user_info);
```

You can change the USERID to anything, currently this is setup to display the ID of the logged in user.

Answer (score 9):

```
  $user_info = get_userdata($userid);
  $username = $user_info->user_login;
  $first_name = $user_info->first_name;
  $last_name = $user_info->last_name;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$user_info = get_userdata($current_user->ID);

echo $user_info->roles[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wpcli for this](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/user/meta/list/):
In the console type...

```
wp user meta list user
```

user = The user login, user email, or user ID of the user to get metadata for.

Answer (score -1):

simply try this

```
$user_info = get_userdata($userid);
var_dump($user_info);
```