# Custom Wordpress page, user profile information in certain divs

Tags: wordpress, user-profile, custom-pages

I created a custom Wordpress page and would like user profile information to be displayed in divs on the page.

For example: A user's profile photo would automatically populate in a div called user-photo, a user biography would automatically be populated in a div called Background, etc.

So, I already have the page structure created. I just need help on how to have certain user information populate in certain divs.

I appreciate any help with this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have answer to this question. For example here - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411110/wordpress-how-to-get-all-user-meta-data-by-user-id). Generally, you must work with functions, that allows you to get user data, for example `get_userdata()` - [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata)

Comment: I was thinking maybe an individual post or page could automatically be created when a new user/member is created. I’ll look into the codex and see if I can make it work. Thanks again for the help.